# Dijkstra's Algorithm - Infinite loop

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, dijkstra

While running Dijkstra's Algorithm to assign a direction to every tile and when an object land on the tile, follow the direction to a goal. I encountered an infinite loop (or I think it is). The following is my code:

```
while (openList.Count > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Running alg");
        failsafe++;
        if (failsafe > 1000) { break; }

        Tile currentTile = openList[0];
        openList.Remove(currentTile);
        closedList.Add(currentTile);

        List<Tile> neighbours = GetNeighbours(currentTile.localX, currentTile.localY, grid);

        foreach (var neighbour in neighbours)
        {
            if (!closedList.Contains(neighbour))
            {
                neighbour.parentX = currentTile.localX;
                neighbour.parentY = currentTile.localY;
                openList.Add(neighbour);
            }
        }
    }
```

Under these conditions, the failsafe triggered and broke the loop. The grid is a 11x11 grid and as such by my understanding should have never reached 1000 cycles.

When the failsafe triggers, it explored 9 tiles away from the goal and the rest are unexplored.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: print out the tiles it is exploring and see what happens. My guess is that the closedList.Contains call always returns false and will then loop forever.

Comment: @ratchetfreak It appears that that is the case. Some tiles are explored once while others are explored up to 100 times. How would I check if the closed list contains the tile already if .contains return false?

Comment: I assume the problem is in tiles ending up on your openlist multiple times rather than being on your closedlist. They only get added to your closed list after they have been on your open list, nothing is stopping tiles from being added to the open list multiple times

Comment: Normally you would change the equals method (or similar) of Tile so it only compares the localX and localY fields.

Comment: @ratchetfreak What do I have to override in order for the .Contains to work?

Comment: What language is this in? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Unity, C#

Comment: This isn't Dijkstra's algorithm, this is (a buggy and low-performance) breadth-first search. This makes me unsure what kind of help you need. Do you want to make this a correct implementation of (depth- or) breadth-first search (enumerates all connected tiles), or a correct implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm (finds shortest paths to all connected tiles)? Either way, this is algorithms 101, which should be answered adequately on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) - it doesn't look like your issues here are game-specific.

Comment: [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) is an algorithm for finding the shortest path from start to destination. Where in that code are the start and destination points? It appears you either completely misunderstood the algorithm or you actually have a completely different problem which you need a completely different algorithm for. Either way, this question belongs on hold for now.

Comment: @DMGregory By my understanding, the difference between Dijkstra's algorithm and breadth first search is tile cost. If the cost is irrelevent, which would it fall under? The question might be posted in the wrong community I would agree.

Comment: @Philipp My destination is every tile and I do not care about the distance. My objective is to assign a direction to every tile and when an object land on the tile, follow the direction to the goal.

Comment: @DarkDestry You can use (a variation of) Dijkstra's algorithm for that, but the code you posted still has no goal.

Comment: DarkDestry: When node distances are interchangeable then Dijkstra's behaves the same as breadth-first search in that it finds a path that minimizes the number of hops - so you can get a simpler implementation by using a standard BFS with a visited flag and a queue. 

@Philipp I presume here they're trying to use the "single-source shortest paths" flavour which finds a path to all connected tiles (no one goal), and that the source is specified by seeding the open list outside of the code shown here.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes! That is precisely what I am trying to achieve. I am doing this for a tower defence game and I require every monster to know where to go to reach the goal. I was thinking that I assign a parent to each tile in order for the mob to read, and then follow each parent to the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aw, what the heck. I'm pretty sure this question belongs on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) but my inner algorithm geek won't let this go without showing a classic [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) implementation...

```
void FindShortestHopcountPaths(Tilemap map, Tile start)
{
    foreach(Tile tile in map.GetTiles())
       tile.visited = false;

    start.parent = start;
    start.visited = true;
    start.hopCount = 0;

    var queue = new Queue<Tile>();
    queue.Enqueue(start);

    while(queue.Count > 0)
    {
         var parent = queue.Dequeue();
         foreach(Tile child in parent.Neighbours)
         {
             if(child.visited)
                 continue;

             child.visited = true;
             child.parent = parent;
             child.hopCount = parent.hopCount + 1;

             queue.Enqueue(child);
         }
    }   
}
```

By the way, if you like geeking out over algorithms like this, [there's a fantastic free course online](https://www.coursera.org/course/algo) where I learned pretty much everything I know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your current algorithm is not dijkstra. Instead it's breadth first floodfill with a buggy loop elimination. Dijkstra implies that you sort the open list according tot he cost of the tile.

Fixing the loop check requires something like:

```
if (!closedList.Exists(n => (n.localX == currentTile.localX &&
                             n.localY == currentTile.localY)))
{
    if (!openList.Exists(n => (n.localX == currentTile.localX &&
                                 n.localY == currentTile.localY)))
    {//also check the open list
        neighbour.parentX = currentTile.localX;
        neighbour.parentY = currentTile.localY;
        openList.Add(neighbour);
    } 
}
```

Adding the sorting requires that you keep a cost field in each Tile that is defaulted to the max value;

```
foreach (var neighbour in neighbours)
{
    if (!closedList.Exists(n => (n.localX == currentTile.localX &&
                                 n.localY == currentTile.localY)))
    {
        if (!openList.Exists(n => (n.localX == currentTile.localX &&
                                     n.localY == currentTile.localY)))
        {//new value
            neighbour.cost = currentTile.cost + currentTile.traverselCost;
            neighbour.parentX = currentTile.localX;
            neighbour.parentY = currentTile.localY;
            openList.Add(neighbour);
        } 
        else
        {
            auto newCost = currentTile.cost + currentTile.traverselCost;
            if(newCost < neighbour.cost){
                neighbour.cost = newCost;
                neighbour.parentX = currentTile.localX;
                neighbour.parentY = currentTile.localY;
            }
        }
    }
}
openList.sort((x, y) =>{return x.cost.CompareTo(y.cost);} );
```